# How to prevent keyboard push up webview at Android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have an EditText and a WebView in a layout(xml). The WebView is at the bottom of the screen.

When I touch the EditText, the keyboard push up the webview to the upper part of the keyboard, and as result it covers the EditText.

I want maintain the webview at the bottom of my screen, displayed or not displayed the keyboard.

Excuse my English, Im not American.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) will help:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan` in AndroidManifest.xml for your activity. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

put this in your menifes in your activity tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Done